# MISRA-C: 2012 violation an increment (++) in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, increment, misra

Using Undertand Tools of SciTool, I have the following `MISRA-C: 2012` violation

`Rule 13.3: A full expression containing an increment (++) or decrement (--) operator should have no other potential side effects other than that caused by the increment or decrement operator - MISRA12_13.3`

on the line `for (i = 0; i < no; i++)`. I have not clear how to correct this violation if it's possible to correct

```
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        p->g->sets[i].ptr = p->g->setbits + css*(i/CHAR_BIT);

    (void) memset((char *)p->g->setbits + (nbytes - css), 0, css);
}
```

The complete code is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/C6ri4BXu) (part of the [LLVM project](http://llvm.org/), file `regcomp.c`). Futhermore, this is the screen of the tool

[image]

Comment: I think you can use `i += 1`

Comment: That looks like a false positive. The only full expression containing a `++` operator is the `i++` in the `for` loop, and it has no other side effects. Either your tool has a bug, or there's something in your actual code that you haven't shown us. Can you update your question with a [mcve] that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I update my question

Comment: As a side-note that's quite some ugly code base there. Trying to make that crap pass MISRA compliance will be torture...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using i++ in a well-formed loop @StaceyGirl

Comment: @Andrew There is nothing wrong with lots of things that MISRA-C forbids. I don't think it forbids increments though.

Comment: Feel free to offer examples, StaceyGirl - each Rule offers a rationale for why it exists